# Can bufferReader be in different class and then call it to the main class?

Tags: java, bufferedreader, filereader, reader

I want to be able to read a txt file and call bufferReader from a different class to main, is that possible? **Basically I want the console to ask the user to place the txt file he wants and if it exists, then he can read it and show it to the console.**

```
Public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Give me the path or the name of the file you want to encrypt : ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String checker = scanner.nextLine();
            if (checker.contains(".txt")) {
                try {
                    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(checker);
                    Scanner sc = new Scanner(inputStream);
                    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("copy-"+checker));
                    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                        sb.append("\n" + sc.nextLine());

                    }
                    sc.close();
                    System.out.println(sb);
                    System.out.println(AES.encrypt(sb.toString()));
//                  append the result and make a new file... H-O-W?
                    bw.write(AES.encrypt(sb.toString()));
                    System.out.println(AES.decrypt(AES.encrypt(sb.toString())));
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("The file does not exists.");
            }
```

**Instead of Public static void main i want a class like (class BufferReader{} called by the main class)**

Thank you all and sorry for my english!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read about Object and classes. For your help you can solve your problem like this.

```
class Main {
    Public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
          MyBuffClass c = new MyBuffClass();
          c.doStuff();
    }
}


class MyBuffClass {
    public void doStuff() {
        System.out.println("Give me the path or the name of the file you want to encrypt : ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String checker = scanner.nextLine();
            if (checker.contains(".txt")) {
                try {
                    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(checker);
                    Scanner sc = new Scanner(inputStream);
                    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("copy-"+checker));
                    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                        sb.append("\n" + sc.nextLine());

                    }
                    sc.close();
                    System.out.println(sb);
                    System.out.println(AES.encrypt(sb.toString()));
//                  append the result and make a new file... H-O-W?
                    bw.write(AES.encrypt(sb.toString()));
                    System.out.println(AES.decrypt(AES.encrypt(sb.toString())));
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("The file does not exists.");
            }
    }
}
```